Luggage Transfer at IGI Airport for International Departure on same PNR (Self or Airline)
Whenever I fly from Istanbul to IGI Delhi, I have to self transfer my luggage at IGI for my onward domestic India journey. This is the case even when the entire journey is on the same PNR. My question is "is it the same for connecting International Departures at IGI"?
I have booked Lufthansa tickets and the domestic leg is operated by Air India. Lufthansa reduced the layover time after a month of booking due to delay of the Air India departure. I am in a dilemma whether I should cancel or accept the new time? I have 2 hours at IGI. Which I feel is risky if I am doing the luggage transfer (self).

I think it is more about custom check: the baggage will not (usually) be checked after a domestic flight, so it is very common to get baggages, pass custom and give the baggage back. -- There are always exceptions, and it may depends on the arrival airport (which you didn't mentioned)

Thanks..The entire journey is Kolkata to Delhi(operated by Air India) and Delhi to Munich (operated by Lufthansa)...I booked tickets from Lufthansa for the whole journey.

Typically that would not be the case for an domestic to international connection, but could be for a international to domestic (because of customs). Did you the encounter this only when flying from IST to India or also the other way around ?

Thanks Hilmar..encountered also when travelling from Warsaw to IGI Delhi...from what I know..this is procedure at IGI for "an international to domestic" connection

Anecdotal: We flew BOM->DEL->LHR->BOS in January on a single PNR.  But if I recall correctly our bags were checked through so we didn't need to lug them.
On the other hand transferring terminals (1 to 3) in DEL was a royal pain. There is a bus, but it only shows up occasionally and some people have to pay. It's a very long ride. Our departure terminal had entry controls at the doors and that was extremely slow and painful since every second person was turned away and huge arguments flared up. At some point the senior officer just went inside and locked the door. The junior officer claimed he couldn't let anyone in without the senior being there. They resumed processing only after my partner gave them a stern talking to along the lines "we have a flight to catch, what do you suggest we do?"
Already having a boarding pass or status didn't help here either. The control is just for entering the terminal in the first place. Once we were inside, things like security and passport control went reasonably fast.
Obviously that depends on the exact terminal combo but I would NOT be happy with with a 2 hour layover for our specific case, luggage or not.

Thanks Hilmar..may I know the airline?..my friend has the same experience with Air India...Bangalore->Delhi->Copenhagen..airline took care of luggage transfers

That was Vistara to Virgin Atlantic on a Virgin Atlantic ticket.

Thanks a lot Hilmar!
